# Load whole page with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load whole page into my browser using ajax. I want it to look like general page navigation (like when user clicks some link). 
I have a select tag, and want to navigate to appropriate page when select is selected.

I guess I have to do it with ajax, 
I am trying like that:

```html
 courseSelect.on('change', function(){
        var courseId = this.value;
        // start search of the course by courseId
        $(document).load('/courses/'+courseId+'');
    });
```

I get my html response, but nothing happens.

Comment: Use snippets only for working HTML / CSS / JS combined.

Answer (score 1):

Use `body` instead of `document`:

```
$("body").load('/courses/'+courseId);
```

Also I would advice you to use a container instead of loading it fully on the document.

Something like this would what I would suggest you:

```
$("#content").html('<img src="loading.gif" />').load('/courses/'+courseId);
```